# Django payload before sending

Tags: python, json, django

This is a code to send invoice via , but I cannot enter a " for loop " loop on it to put product name and price and quantity of it , so how to deal with this to put products and other data , I tried to add for loop but it didn't work ,

```py
###########Send Payment###########
baseURL = "https://apitest.myfatoorah.com"
token = 'rLtt6JWvbUHDDhsZnfpAhpYk4dxYDQkbcPTyGaKp2TYqQgG7FGZ5Th_WD53Oq8Ebz6A53njUoo1w3pjU1D4vs_ZMqFiz_j0urb_BH9Oq9VZoKFoJEDAbRZepGcQanImyYrry7Kt6MnMdgfG5jn4HngWoRdKduNNyP4kzcp3mRv7x00ahkm9LAK7ZRieg7k1PDAnBIOG3EyVSJ5kK4WLMvYr7sCwHbHcu4A5WwelxYK0GMJy37bNAarSJDFQsJ2ZvJjvMDmfWwDVFEVe_5tOomfVNt6bOg9mexbGjMrnHBnKnZR1vQbBtQieDlQepzTZMuQrSuKn-t5XZM7V6fCW7oP-uXGX-sMOajeX65JOf6XVpk29DP6ro8WTAflCDANC193yof8-f5_EYY-3hXhJj7RBXmizDpneEQDSaSz5sFk0sV5qPcARJ9zGG73vuGFyenjPPmtDtXtpx35A-BVcOSBYVIWe9kndG3nclfefjKEuZ3m4jL9Gg1h2JBvmXSMYiZtp9MR5I6pvbvylU_PP5xJFSjVTIz7IQSjcVGO41npnwIxRXNRxFOdIUHn0tjQ-7LwvEcTXyPsHXcMD8WtgBh-wxR8aKX7WPSsT1O8d8reb2aR7K3rkV3K82K_0OgawImEpwSvp9MNKynEAJQS6ZHe_J_l77652xwPNxMRTMASk1ZsJL'

def send_payment():
url = baseURL + "/v2/SendPayment"
payload = "{\"CustomerName\": \"Ahmed\",\"NotificationOption\": \"ALL\",\"MobileCountryCode\": \"+965\"," \
              "\"CustomerMobile\": \"12345678\",\"CustomerEmail\": \"xx@yy.com\",\"InvoiceValue\": 100," \
              "\"DisplayCurrencyIso\": \"KWD\",\"CallBackUrl\": \"https://google.com\",\"ErrorUrl\": " \
              "\"https://google.com\",\"Language\": \"en\",\"CustomerReference\": \"ref 1\",\"CustomerCivilId\": " \
              "12345678,\"UserDefinedField\": \"Custom field\",\"ExpireDate\": \"\",\"CustomerAddress\": {\"Block\": " \
              "\"\",\"Street\": \"\",\"HouseBuildingNo\": \"\",\"Address\": \"\",\"AddressInstructions\": \"\"}," \
              "\"InvoiceItems\": [{\"ItemName\": \"Product 01\",\"Quantity\": 1,\"UnitPrice\": 100}]} "
headers = {'Content-Type': "application/json", 'Authorization': "Bearer " + token}
response = requests.request("POST", url, data=payload, headers=headers)
print("Send Payment Response:\n" + response.text)
```

I tried this and made for loop but it didn't work

```py
    url = baseURL + "/v2/SendPayment"

    sss={'ItemName': 'product 01',
                    'Quantity': 30,
                    'UnitPrice': 10,},

    payload={
                "CustomerName": "name",  # Mandatory Field ("string")
                "NotificationOption": "SMS",  # Mandatory Field ("LNK", "SMS", "EML", or "ALL")
                "InvoiceValue": 300,  # Mandatory Field (Number)
            # Optional Fields
                "MobileCountryCode": "+966",
                "CustomerMobile": "12345678", #Mandatory if the NotificationOption = SMS or ALL
                # "CustomerEmail": "mail@company.com", #Mandatory if the NotificationOption = EML or ALL
                "DisplayCurrencyIso": "kwd",
                "CallBackUrl": "https://yoursite.com/success",
                "ErrorUrl": "https://yoursite.com/error",
                "Language": "ar",
                # "CustomerReference": "noshipping-nosupplier",
                # "CustomerAddress": {
                #     "Block": "string",
                #     "Street": "string",
                #     "HouseBuildingNo": "string",
                #     "Address": "address",
                #     "AddressInstructions": "string"
                #     },
                "InvoiceItems": [
                   sss
                    ]
            }
    payload=str(payload)
    print(f"this is pyload: {payload}")
    print(f"this is sss: {sss}")    
    headers = {'Content-Type': "application/json", 'Authorization': "Bearer " + token}
    response = requests.request("POST", url, data=payload2, headers=headers)
    print("Send Payment Response:\n" + response.text)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `data` parameter in requests.request should be a `dict`, in other word, don't convert `payload` into string, make it `dict`.

Comment: the main problem here is how to add many products to payload itself

Comment: Ok, I want to see output or error message currently, plz edit into question.